# LWUIT - Create new line in Flowlayout

Tags: java-me, lwuit

from flying through the source code of the HTMLComponent, the method for creating a line break in a Form filled with labels the proper method is embedding the labels in a container and the newline actually creates a new container. 
Is this the proper way to do it?

So: 
Container
|Label Label
|Label Label
|Label
|Label

Container:
|Label
|Label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow layout can and should perform its own line breaks on entered text. The reason the HTML component does this manually is to provide it with even more fine grained control over layout.

Generally you need to see why HTMLComponent doesn't wrap lines for you, you need to look in the LWUITBrowser demo and the LWUITDemo both of which line wrap properly and see what you did differently.

Comment: I'm not really looking into breaking a line but how to insert a new empty line, right now I'm inserting a new Container with an empty label in it - doesn't seem to be the proper way I think..

Comment: If you want to manually break lines just create a box layout Y container and nest into it containers with flow layout.